# Checkbox saves but return "empty" on Oracle ADF Faces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I have a timely demand where I have a Checkbox in the view that - when checked - update the record in the database, everything OK, but when I access the same record - the same Checkbox - returns "empty", appears unchecked on the screen...

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: How the items in checkbox are assigned?

Comment: Is it coming from database or directly you are assigning items?

Comment: This checkbox need to be a boolean in your VO. (As transient eventuall) If it is, just add immediate="true" to your jsf checkbox component.

Comment: As <af:selectBooleanCheckbox>. And yes: it is coming from the database. I answered your questions? cc @Shaili

Comment: I set immediate="true" but this doesn't change the component's behaviour... cc @MrAdibou

Comment: You need to give selected value and unselected value in checkbox binding? Have you tried to give it

Answer (score 0):

If its a database attribute then please confirm selecOneCheckbox binding in pageDef and ensure that you are saving same values in DB that you are using in pageDef bindings.